# Как синхронизировать treeView с источником данных?

Tags: c#, winforms

Сохраняю, читаю treeView  с помощью класса

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

public class TreeViewSerializer
{
    public TreeViewSerializer() { }

    public TreeViewSerializer(TreeView treeView)
    {
        this.TreeView = treeView;
    }

    public TreeView TreeView { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
        if (this.TreeView == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("TreeView can not be null");
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        var declaration = document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        document.AppendChild(declaration);
        var root = document.CreateElement("treeview");
        document.AppendChild(root);
        for(int i = 0; i < this.TreeView.Nodes.Count; i++)
            root.AppendChild(SerializeNode(this.TreeView.Nodes[i], root, document));
        document.Save(fileName);
    }

    public void Deserialize(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
        this.TreeView.Nodes.Clear();
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(fileName);
        var root = document.DocumentElement;
        for(int i = 0; i < root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            TreeView.Nodes.Add(DeseializeNode(root.ChildNodes[i]));
    }

    private XmlElement SerializeNode(TreeNode node, XmlElement root, XmlDocument document)
    {
        XmlElement elem = document.CreateElement("node");
        XmlAttribute attr = document.CreateAttribute("tag");
        XmlAttribute val = document.CreateAttribute("val");
        val.InnerText = node.Text;
        attr.InnerText = node.Tag == null ? "" : node.Tag.ToString();
        elem.Attributes.Append(attr);
        elem.Attributes.Append(val);
        for(int i = 0; i < node.Nodes.Count; i++)
            elem.AppendChild(SerializeNode(node.Nodes[i], elem, document));
        return elem;
    }

    private TreeNode DeseializeNode(XmlNode element)
    {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.Text = element.Attributes["val"].Value;
        treeNode.Tag = element.Attributes["tag"].Value;
        for(int i = 0; i < element.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(DeseializeNode(element.ChildNodes[i]));
        return treeNode;
    }
}
```

С treeView выполняются следующие действия:
 - добавление узлов: родительских, дочерних;
 - удаление узлов;
 - перемещение узлов (влево, вправо, вверх, вниз).

**Вопросы.**
1. После каждого действия нужно сохранять ВСЁ дерево или можно сделать как-то сохранение только изменённых частей или сравнения с источником данных?

или
2. Просто в конце сеанса (перед закрытием формы) нужно сохранять ВСЁ дерево или можно сделать как-то сохранение только изменённых частей или сравнения с источником данных?

или
3. Нужно сохранять только изменённые части, а для этого лучше использовать другие источники данных?
Например БД.

Comment: Сколько у вас будет узлов в дереве: максимум несколько сотен. Объём данных, соответственно, невелик. Поэтому проще всего писать и читать файл целиком. Если реализовывать диффы, то нужно будет сперва читать основной файл, потом по очереди все файлы с изменениями накатывать... Слишком сложно. А xml, в котором вы сделали хранение, не предполагает изменение самого файла, только полную перезапись. Если хранить в БД - тогда можно делать update только изменённых узлов. Но оно действительно надо?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `Если хранить в БД - тогда можно делать update только изменённых узлов. 
Но оно действительно надо?` Наиболее распространённый способа хранения дерева это хранение в XML? Или  зависит от ситуации? И принцип работы: "внёс изменения" -> "сохранил в XML"? Понимаю, что вопрос слишком общий так, что прошу извинить... Хотелось узнать ваш опыт...

Comment: Хранить можно в любом формате. Какой вам удобнее - тот и используйте. Хоть бинарный, хоть json... Отталкивайтесь от размера данных. Если их не очень много - используем файл. Много и нужно менять отдельные части - используем БД. _принцип работы: "внёс изменения" -> "сохранил_ - если изменения нельзя терять (даже в случае, например, отключения питания), то да, сохраняем после каждого изменения. Если изменения не критичны, можно сохранять один раз, в конце работы приложения.